# How can I stop ggdb from unsetting DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: bash, gdb, environment-variables, macports, dyld

I'm setting `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` in my bash `~/.profile` and then call `ggdb` (installed with macports). But if in `ggdb` I issue:

```
(gdb) show environment DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I see

```
Environment variable "DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" not defined.
```

Then, of course, upon trying to debug my binary I get dynamic linker errors:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/libXXXX.dylib
  Referenced from: /XXX/
  Reason: image not found
```

Suppose my ~/.profile looks like:

```
...
export FOO="BAR
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/lib/"
...
```

Then

```
(gdb) show environment FOO
```

works, and I see

```
FOO = BAR
```

My `~/.gdbinit` file is empty. Is there some other initialization that's wiping out this environment variable?

**Note:** This does not happen with the default `gdb`. There, `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` is loaded correctly.